# Is "got insane" a correct sentence with a meaning?

Tags: meaning

First of all: it should be obvious English is not my native language. ;)

A customer of mine just bought a domain, gotinsane, and I am just wondering if it has some meaning and if it is correct English.

Comment: Are you sure it's "got insane" and not "got in sane" or "[Gotin's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludovic_Gotin) [ane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ane)"?

Comment: I guess the wanted meaning was something like "gone crazy", but could be "got in sane"

Comment: I think @Reg was being _drôle_

Comment: Go Go Tin Sane!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *got insane* in something like the following

> That party got insane after you left

is a fairly common way to indicate that the state of affairs became out of control or "insane". (I should note, in this case, insane does not mean literally insane, but is figuratively applied to mean wild or exciting).

The same construction can be pretty widely applied:

> The evening got really depressing after she brought up her friend's illness.
>
> The game got exciting when the final goal sent it to OT.
>
> It got difficult after they introduced the new rule set.

Given that we're just working with a domain name out of context, it could indicate a lot of things, but a site that allows users to show off events that got 'insane' would be a reasonable guess I'd say.

Comment: @mplungjan: Hmm this looks pretty different to me? I suppose we'll never know what some unknown person had in mind with that domain name...

Comment: @mplungjan - As far as I'm aware, the only part of speech that "*insane*" functions as is an adjective (and a couple dictionaries back that up), so I'd say the fact that we both used it as one is a fairly unremarkable similarity.

Answer (score 1):

*I went insane* is the correct way of saying this

You can use *I got insane demands from my boss*
but then it is an adjective

Comment: and couldnt 'got insane' be a sort of slang?

Comment: Please see update

Comment: @DaNieL: almost anything _could be_ a sort of slang.  To the best of my knowledge, "got insane" isn't _currently_ slang for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something similar to the [Got Milk?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Got_Milk%3F) campaign slogan which has been borrowed countless times. I am sure there are hundreds of "Got [noun]" domain names taken in this spirit. Of course I would expect something more like, "Got Insanity?" instead of "Got Insane" though.

As-is, it is very cryptic to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete sentence, and it's... unusual English.

"Get" has quite a lot of meanings as a transitive verb, but most of them centre around the idea of acquiring or obtaining something, not necessarily willingly.  "Insane" is a state of being, and we wouldn't normally "get" it in that sense.

The most likely meaning of "get" to work in this context is "to understand".  "I get that this is complicated, but do try to keep up!"  In that sense, "got insane" means "[I] understood what it means to be insane."  It's a stretch though, and most people wouldn't recognise it.

Comment: _I grokked being insane_ would be more like it, no?

Comment: "Got drunk", "got high", "got wasted" are all customary, but not "got insane", perhaps because it is not something you can do to yourself voluntarily.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to say "Go insane." That would be a complete sentence.